# Look and feel of html page template after storing that in DOCX file with user data

Tags: java, html, css, jsoup

I have developed an HTML and CSS web page template which looks like:

[image: here]
Once the user enters the data on this web page and clicks on the send button. My java application will trigger an e-mail along with a docx file as an attachment, where this docx file should contain the web page template exactly the same as in the above image along with the data the user had entered.

I have achieved this by using the library JSOUP jar as:

```java
File i1 = new File("C:/Users/RPUNEET/Desktop/Puneeth/java/DaimlerLoDATemplate_Demo/WebContent/Template_demo_new.html");
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(i1, "UTF-8");

// For the project name
Element eleprojectname= doc.getElementById("projectname");
eleprojectname.attr("value",iv.getProjectname());

// For the name field
Element elename = doc.getElementById("Name1");
elename.attr("value", iv.getName());

// For the e-mail field
Element eleEmail = doc.getElementById("email");
eleEmail.attr("value", iv.getEmail());
```

I am setting my object data which I took from the servlet request as a value to a particular element-id in the referenced html-file: `Template_demo_new.html`.

After setting all value, this "doc" is being converted to a string to store in the specific file:

```java
String html = doc.html();

WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.createPackage(PageSizePaper.A4, false);
AlternativeFormatInputPart afiPart = new AlternativeFormatInputPart(new PartName("/hw.html"));
afiPart.setBinaryData(html.getBytes());
afiPart.setContentType(new ContentType("text/html"));
Relationship altChunkRel = wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().addTargetPart(afiPart);
//HeaderPart hp=new HeaderPart

// the bit in the document body
CTAltChunk ac = Context.getWmlObjectFactory().createCTAltChunk();

ac.setId(altChunkRel.getId());
wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().addObject(ac);

// content type
wordMLPackage.getContentTypeManager().addDefaultContentType("html", "text/html");
wordMLPackage.save(new java.io.File("C:/Users/RPUNEET/Desktop/RajPuneeth/LoDA_BRD_Template_v1.0.docx"));
```

The code is storing the web template along with the user data. But the look and feel of the document docx file is not exactly the same as the web page template where the size and background colour are not applied as in the html web page as shown:

[image: here]

Please let me know what I have to do in order to achieve the same look and feel in the e-mail version as in the html-template?

Comment: The browser and the email client are not going to render html _exactly_ the same. You'll want to create a template for each.

Comment: No, template is common for all ,as am handling this from session.Once the user clicks submit button at last after filling fields. My applcation is take the data from request and assign this to a Template_demo.html and Jsoup jar converts this html into a java string and puts in a docx file as shown in the code above and trigger a mail with this file as attachment.